# How to make listener for setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am working in a project which opens a dialog with image when user selects an image. Now due to requirement I have to close the dialog when touched on outside of dialog so I set the `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`.
But another requirement says that I should change the page as soon as user touches out side the dialog so I was trying to find out how to do that. But I have tried both `onCancelListener` and `onDismissListener`. None of them get called when we use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`. to cancel dialog.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `DialogFragment` class, just override its `onCancel()` method:

```
@Override public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you can't add additional handling with setCanceledOnTouchOutside
as an alternative you can override your onTouchEvent to do stuff when they touch outside the box using MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE like so

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  
{  

   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
           doStuff(); 
           this.dismiss();  
   }  
   return false;  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my case. Is there an alternative?